I can't get NSolve to work
I have defined the function ekert the following way;
gammaFunc[n_, k_, merr_, m_] := 1/(merr + 1) + 1/(m - merr + 1);

ekert[nu_, eta_, ntrials_, nsucc_, ntot_] := 
  Exp[-2 ntot ntrials  eta^2/(ntot - ntrials + 1)] + 
   Exp[-2 gammaFunc[ntot - ntrials, ntrials, 
       ntot (nsucc/ntrials + eta), 
       ntot] (ntot - ntrials)^2 (nu - eta)^2 - 1];

For my problem, ntot>ntrials>2*nsucc (all integers) and 0.5-nsucc/ntrials>nu>eta>0.
Given ntot,ntrials,nsucc,nu I can minimize ekert by optimising over eta, no problem;
ntot = 10^4;
ntrials = 8 10^3;
nsucc = 5 10^2;
nu = 0.09;(*0.5 - nsucc/ntrials=0.4375*)

NMinimize[{ekert[nu, eta, ntrials, nsucc, ntot], 0 < eta < nu}, 
 eta \[Element] Reals]

(*{3.7057*10^-20,{eta->0.0239982}}*)

However what I really need is to solve for nu and eta given ekert,ntot,nsucc,ntrials. I tried NSolve but it did not work.
Clear[nu, eta]
ntot = 10^4;
ntrials = 8 10^3;
nsucc = 5 10^2; 
NSolve[ekert[nu, eta, ntrials, nsucc, ntot] == 3.7057 10.^-20 && 
  0 < eta < nu < 0.5 - nsucc/ntrials, {eta, nu}, Reals]

(*NSolve[E^(-((160000000 eta^2)/2001)) + 
    E^(-1 - 8000000 (-eta + nu)^2 (1/(
        10001 - Ceiling[10000 (1/16 + eta)]) + 1/(
        1 + Ceiling[10000 (1/16 + eta)]))) == 3.7057*10^-20 && 
  0 < eta < nu < 0.4375, {eta, nu}, Reals]*)

What should I do? How can I get NSolve to give me the answer?

Is this close enough? NMinimize[{(ekert[nu,eta,ntrials,nsucc,ntot]-3.7057*10^-20)^2, 0<eta<nu<0.5-nsucc/ntrials},{eta,nu}] which returns {1.37307*^-39,{eta->0.0261216,nu->0.351967}} 10^-39 is close to zero. Giving all your constants 32 or 64 or more digits of precision can get you closer if you really need that. The Ceiling  is perhaps what is making it difficult for NSolve

Yeah thanks for your suggestion. If i increase the working precision I can get satisfactory results. Now that I look into it, the Ceiling function is not absolutely necessary.

Although this gets ekert close to the desired value, it seems that the output values for eta and nu varies quite a lot. I want nu to be as small as possible.

For example, setting the WorkingPrecision to 100 give nu=0.165 whereas setting it to 64 gave nu=0.1, which is much better for my application.

Are both nu=0.165 and nu=0.1 both "solutions"? If so then it sounds like you might need to think of a better goal to minimize to get closer to what you really want.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

gammaFunc[n_, k_, merr_, m_] := 1/(merr + 1) + 1/(m - merr + 1);

ekert[nu_, eta_, ntrials_, nsucc_, ntot_] := 
  Exp[-2  ntot  ntrials   eta^2/(ntot - ntrials + 1)] + 
   Exp[-2  gammaFunc[ntot - ntrials, ntrials, ntot  (nsucc/ntrials + eta), 
       ntot]  (ntot - ntrials)^2  (nu - eta)^2 - 1];

ntot = 10^4;
ntrials = 8  10^3;
nsucc = 5  10^2;

cons = ekert[nu, eta, ntrials, nsucc, ntot] == 37057  10^-24;

inst = FindInstance[{cons, 0 < eta < nu < 1/2 - nsucc/ntrials},
  {eta, nu}, 5]


Using the smallest value of eta,
inst[[3, 1]]

(* eta -> Root[{-37057 + 
   1000000000000000000000000 E^(Rational[-160000000, 2001] #^2) + 
   1000000000000000000000000 
    E^(-1 - 8000000 (
        Rational[4, 29] - #)^2 ((10001 - 10000 (Rational[1, 16] + #))^(-1) + (
         1 + 10000 (Rational[1, 16] + #))^(-1)))& , 
   0.0609764526883354021122850286657264546673443087457350793119`30.}] *)

The corresponding minimum value of nu is
(nuMin = ArgMin[{nu, cons, 0 < eta < nu < 1/2 - nsucc/ntrials} /. 
       inst[[3, 1]] // RootReduce, nu]) // N[#, 100] & // N

(* 0.137931 *)

Verifying the constraint,
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, 
 PossibleZeroQ[#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(cons /. inst[[3, 1]] /. nu -> nuMin // 
     FullSimplify)]]

(* bPossibleZeroQ::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity E^((160000000 Root[{<<1>>}]^2)/2001)-E^((160000000 Root[{<<1>>}]^2)/2001) is equal to zero. Assuming it is.

True *)


Clear["Global`*"]

gammaFunc[n_, k_, merr_, m_] := 1/(merr + 1) + 1/(m - merr + 1);

ekert[nu_, eta_, ntrials_, nsucc_, ntot_] := 
  Exp[-2  ntot  ntrials   eta^2/(ntot - ntrials + 1)] + 
   Exp[-2  gammaFunc[ntot - ntrials, ntrials, ntot  (nsucc/ntrials + eta), 
       ntot]  (ntot - ntrials)^2  (nu - eta)^2 - 1];

ntot = 10^4;
ntrials = 8  10^3;
nsucc = 5  10^2;

NMinimize[{nu, (ekert[nu, eta, ntrials, nsucc, ntot] == 10^-20), 
  0 < eta < nu < 1/2 - nsucc/ntrials}, {eta, nu}, AccuracyGoal -> 32, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 32, WorkingPrecision -> 64, MaxIterations ->
  128, Method -> "RandomSearch"]

